# How to integrate CKEditor with Chrome app

Tags: ckeditor

I am trying to integrate CKEditor with Chrome App (packages App). but it is not working, has anyone tried this before?

I was trying to create a sample app, there are two buttons "create editor" and "Remove Editor", 'create editor' button should open an editor where user can create some content(html/text) using ckEditor. and on click of "Remove Editor", the editor should be closed and content should be displayed below text "Edited Contents" on same page.

I am using angularJS for scripting.

here is  code snippet of **index.html**

```
 <div lang="en" ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl" >
     <p>Click the buttons to create and remove a CKEditor instance.</p>
    <p>
        <input ng-click="createEditor()" type="button" value="Create Editor">
        <input ng-click="removeEditor()" type="button" value="Remove Editor">
    </p>
    <!-- This div will hold the editor. -->
    <div id="editor">
    </div>
    <div id="contents" style="display: none">
        <p>
            Edited Contents:
        </p>
        <!-- This div will be used to display the editor contents. -->
        <div id="editorcontents">
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

here is code of **main.js**

```
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', []);

var MainCtrl = function($scope) {
        var editor, html = '';

         $scope.createEditor =function() {
            if ( editor )
                return;

            // Create a new editor inside the <div id="editor">, setting its value to html
            var config = {};
             editor = CKEDITOR.appendTo( 'editor', config, html );
          }

        $scope.removeEditor = function() {
            if ( !editor )
                return;
            document.getElementById( 'editorcontents' ).innerHTML = html = editor.getData();
            document.getElementById( 'contents' ).style.display = '';
            // Destroy the editor.
            editor.destroy();
            editor = null;
        }

   // $scope.Wrapper = Serv;
}

demoApp.controller('MainCtrl',MainCtrl);
```

if i am running this example as web application it runs fine. but when i convert it into packaged chrome app, it throws below error on debug console

```
document.open() is not available in packaged apps.extensions::platformApp:17
Uncaught Error: document.write() is not available in packaged apps.extensions::platformApp:31
```

Please help.

Comment: What exactly have you tried and is not working?  Please post your config/code.

Comment: added more content/Code

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem might be in the lack of access to certain API methods in this environment. A bit of googling lead me to [this link](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/chromium-apps/QD8_2THbo7M/AjhJFgA3PzEJ):

> New Packaged apps, specifically those with manifest_version:2 are not able to use document.write directly or load scripts in between script elements.
>
> You can use the sandbox where all these features are enabled, so check out http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/apps/app_external.html#external

CKEditor needs access to `document.write` in the [wysiwygarea plugin](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/wysiwygarea/plugin.js#L467), which is used by the *classic* editor. As the simplest workaround you may try using [inline editor](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/inline.html) instead to see if that will help (if you need inline editor with Fixed UI, check the second sample [here](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/fixedui.html)).

Comment: Actually we are looking for solution which can run without SandBoxing, can your team help us on this?

Comment: Check the mentioned inline editor: http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/inline.html At the bottom of the sample check "Get Sample Source code" -> "Inline editing enabled by code"

Comment: inline editing is not working with chrome packaged app, getting error on console     `Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' chrome-  ckeditor.js:289`